# Why used heap is always increasing in my MINA application?

Tags: java, performance, memory, mina

I have an application which consists of two parts as server and client.

It works like this :

Client connects to the server and sends a string; server receives the string and returns an ArrayList (by converting string) which contains 10000 elements.

I wrote a class (ClientConnector.java) which simulates many clients use one connection to take those 10000 elements from server.

When I run this two programs, server side is ok. However on the client side, used heap is always increasing ! I tried to release the used objects by "null" but the used memory is still getting larger and larger.

http://s10.postimage.org/egf4ugrd5/mem.png

My Server Side Codes : 
Client.java

public class Client {

```
private static final int PORT = 7571;
ClientHandler handler = new ClientHandler("hey");
IoConnector connector;
boolean available = true;

public synchronized void setAvailable(boolean available) {
    this.available = available;
}

public synchronized boolean isAvailable() {
    return available;
}

public void starter() throws InterruptedException {

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            connector = new NioSocketConnector();
            connector.getSessionConfig().setReadBufferSize(2048);
            TextLineCodecFactory t = new TextLineCodecFactory(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            t.setEncoderMaxLineLength(20 * 150000);
            t.setDecoderMaxLineLength(20 * 150000);
            connector.getFilterChain().addLast("logger", new LoggingFilter());
            connector.getFilterChain().addLast("codec", new ProtocolCodecFilter(t));

            connector.setHandler(handler);
            ConnectFuture future = connector.connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", PORT));
            future.awaitUninterruptibly();

            if (!future.isConnected()) {
                return;
            }

            IoSession session = future.getSession();
            session.getConfig().setUseReadOperation(true);
            session.getCloseFuture().awaitUninterruptibly();

            connector.dispose();
        }
    });
    t.start();
    Thread.sleep(300);
}

public void conClose() {
    connector.dispose();
}

public ClientHandler getHandler() {
    return handler;
}

public void reqInf() {
    handler.reqInfo();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Client c = new Client();
        c.starter();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        System.out.println("error");
    }
}
```

}

ClientHandler.java

public class ClientHandler extends IoHandlerAdapter {

```
long time;
private final String values;
IoSession session;

public ClientHandler(String values) {
    this.values = values;
}

@Override
public void sessionOpened(IoSession session) throws InterruptedException {
    this.session = session;
}

public ArrayList<String> convert(String str) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.fromJson(str, ArrayList.class);
}

@Override
public void messageReceived(IoSession session, Object message) throws InterruptedException {

    try {
        ArrayList<String> test = convert(message.toString());
        System.out.println("TIME : " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time) + " strList:" + test.size());
        message = null;
        test = null;

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void exceptionCaught(IoSession session, Throwable cause) {
    session.close();
    System.out.println(cause.toString());
}

@Override
public void sessionClosed(IoSession session) {

    System.out.println("Connection Lost");
}

public void reqInfo() {
    time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    session.write("test");
}
```

}

**My Server Side :**
Server.java

public class Server {

```
private static final int PORT = 7571; //TEST PORT
IoAcceptor acceptor = new NioSocketAcceptor();

public Server() throws IOException {
    TextLineCodecFactory t = new TextLineCodecFactory(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    t.setEncoderMaxLineLength(20*150000);
    t.setDecoderMaxLineLength(20*150000);
    acceptor.getFilterChain().addLast("logger", new LoggingFilter());
    acceptor.getFilterChain().addLast("codec", new ProtocolCodecFilter(t));
    // acceptor.getFilterChain().addLast("threadPool", new ExecutorFilter(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()));

    Executor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(5, 70, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());

    acceptor.getFilterChain().addLast("threadPool", new ExecutorFilter(executor));
    acceptor.setHandler(new ServerHandler());
    acceptor.getSessionConfig().setReadBufferSize(2048);
    acceptor.getSessionConfig().setIdleTime(IdleStatus.BOTH_IDLE, 1000);

    //timer();

    acceptor.bind(new InetSocketAddress(PORT));
    System.out.println("***Mina Server is ready !");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("");


}


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Server m = new Server();
}
```

}

ServerHandler.java

public class ServerHandler extends IoHandlerAdapter {

```
private final Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
IoSession sessions;
//Communication communication;

public ServerHandler() throws IOException {
    loader();
    // communication = new Communication(this);
}

@Override
public void sessionOpened(IoSession session) {
    // set idle time to 10 seconds
    session.getConfig().setIdleTime(IdleStatus.BOTH_IDLE, 1000);
    System.out.println("Client Connected !!!");
    //session.setAttribute("Values: ");
    this.sessions = session;

}

public String toGSon(ArrayList<String> list) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String str = gson.toJson(list);
    return str;
}
ArrayList<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();

public void loader() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        str.add("test" + i);
    }
}

@Override
public void messageReceived(IoSession session, Object message) throws InterruptedException {

    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    session.write(toGSon(str));
    System.out.println("TIME : " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));

}

@Override
public void sessionIdle(IoSession session, IdleStatus status) {
    System.out.println("Socket #" + session.getId() + " is disconnecting... (IDLE)");
    session.close();
}

@Override
public void exceptionCaught(IoSession session, Throwable cause) {
    System.out.println("------------>" + cause.toString());
    session.close();
}
```

}

And my Main Class

public class ClientConnector {

```
public ClientConnector() throws InterruptedException {
    Client cl = new Client();
    cl.starter();
    while (true) {

        cl.reqInf();
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ClientConnector cl = new ClientConnector();
}
```

}

Comment: did u try to forcefully call GC during the period when Heap is increasing?

Comment: can you share the heap statistics of profiling tool that you are using ?

Comment: I think, calling GC manually is not a proper way. Here is the statistics http://s13.postimage.org/5dqc33k0n/mem2.png

Comment: You should post minimal code that reproduces the problem. Also structure your code properly, like fields first then methods. This is a mess nobody will want to look through.

Comment: I know but it was for just once to test whether there is a leak or GC was not run in that time period :) `t.setEncoderMaxLineLength(20*150000);` what does this line do?

Comment: Seems like either the GC was not run or the char[] references are leaking from somewhere!

Comment: server sends large data. This line determines the max length of receiving data.

Comment: @m0skit0 sorry for this situation, but the problem could be anywhere on my applicaton. Furthermore, this code is only a simple not my entire application. My question is not about java exceptions or etc..

Answer (score 2):

You must remove below code from client side.

```
session.getConfig().setUseReadOperation(true);
```

Above code will cause memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

One of our developers found an issue in Mina with the way clean up was being done and a patch was applied to version 2.0.8. Since as of today this is "snapshot" you have to grab it from git and build it yourself. Here is the command to get it from git:

```
git checkout 2.0
```

Repository uri:

```
git clone http://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/mina.git
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is not enough to reach to a pin pointed answer.

Heap size continuous increase and no effect of GC --> Signs of memory leak.

Probably you should **Profile** your application and use some [OQL Tools](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.mat.ui.help/tasks/queryingheapobjects.html) to find out which class is using `char[]`, which here is the culprit looking at heap dump in your case

Comment: Actually, both Server and Client side runs on their own threads and listens each other. Is it possible that the reason of this situation is thread local variables ? Please look at messageReceived method on ClientHandler. The "message" object is a huge string. Is it possible that GC ignores this string eachtime ?

Comment: that should not be a problem unless both Threads free unused references. As you say there is lots of code only way to find out is where the references are used using OQL.